# Ng-repeat not working with Flask, $scope.variablename = data.result goes out of scope after $.post API call

Tags: javascript, angularjs, python-3.x, flask, angularjs-ng-repeat

I'm trying to populate a table using data from database using ng-repeat. After the `$.post` call `$scope.variable_name = data.result` gets data from flask, but it goes out of scope making the variable used in ng-repeat null. Thus I'm getting blanks inside HTML tags.

I tried declaring a global $scope.variable1 and assigning the data from flask, but it still doesn't work.

HTML code:

```html
div class="row card_row margin-bottom-10" ng-repeat="item in userdata">
    <div class="col-md-3">
        <span>{{item.name}}</span>
    </div>
    <div class="col-md-3">
        <span>{{item.number}}</span>
    </div>
    <div class="col-md-3">
        <span>{{item.email}}</span>
    </div>
</div>
```

Javascript code:

```
User.controller("UserController", function ($scope, $rootScope, $window, $http) {
    $scope.getUserDetails = function getUserDetails() {
        $.post('/getDetails', function (data) {
            $scope.userdata = data.result;
            console.log("log1: ",$scope.userdata);//second in console //prints 
             data
        });
        console.log("log2: ",$scope.userdata);//first in console //prints 
             null
    }
});
```

Python-flask code:

```py
@app.route('/getDetails', methods=["POST","GET"])
def getDetails():
    to_send=[{'name': 'abcd', 'number': 1234567890, 'email': 'abcd@abcd.com'}, 
    {'name': 'efgh', 'number': 1234567890, 'email': 'efgh@abcd.com'}, 
    {'name': 'ijkl', 'number': 1234567890, 'email': 'ijkl@abcd.com'}]   
    return jsonify(result=to_send)
```

I expect the details passed to $scope from flask to be usable by ng-repeat and print the data in a tabular format. But the output I'm getting is blanks in {{item.name}} and other {{}} tags since the $scope.userdata goes out of scope.

Current Console Output:

```html
log2: undefined
log1: [{'name': 'abcd', 'number': 1234567890, 'email': 'abcd@abcd.com'}, 
      {'name': 'efgh', 'number': 1234567890, 'email': 'efgh@abcd.com'}, 
      {'name': 'ijkl', 'number': 1234567890, 'email': 'ijkl@abcd.com'}]
```

Comment: You want to populate the Table but on your HTML code, you have a div instead of Table with the tags <table><tr><td></td></tr></table>

Comment: Instead of the $.post code you should have something like $scope.userdata.push({name: $scope.newAgent.name, number: $scope.newAgent.number, email: $scope.newAgent.email});

Comment: $.post is for the flask API call, which returns data from database. To reduce the code I didn't add the database part. So we can't remove $.post part. Any other solution for this?

Answer (score 1):

It looks like you're using jQuery's `$.post` method for your ajax call - any particular reason? It's better use Angular's `$http.post` method. Here's a version of your code that works for me:

```
<!-- get_details.html template -->
<!doctype html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, user-scalable=no, initial-scale=1.0, maximum-scale=1.0, minimum-scale=1.0">
  <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="ie=edge">
  <title>Document</title>
  <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/angular.js/1.7.8/angular.min.js"></script>
  <script>
    var User = angular.module('User', []);
    User.controller("UserController", function ($scope, $rootScope, $window, $http) {
      $scope.userdata = [];
      $scope.getUserDetails = function getUserDetails() {
        $http.post('/getDetails').then(function (data) {
          $scope.userdata = data.data.result;
          console.log("log1: ", $scope.userdata);//second in console //prints data
        });
        console.log("log2: ", $scope.userdata);//first in console //prints null
      };
    });
  </script>
</head>
{% raw %}
<body ng-app="User" ng-controller="UserController">
<button ng-click="getUserDetails()">Fetch userdata</button>
<div class="row card_row margin-bottom-10" ng-repeat="item in userdata">
  <div class="col-md-3">
    <span>{{ item.name }}</span>
  </div>
  <div class="col-md-3">
    <span>{{ item.number }}</span>
  </div>
  <div class="col-md-3">
    <span>{{ item.email }}</span>
  </div>
</div>
</body>
{% endraw %}
</html>
```

I did not have to make any changes to your backend code, just the frontend.

Comment: `$http` did the trick. But I had to pass parameters so this worked for me.

```$http({
    url: '/getRoomDetails',
    method: "POST",
    headers: { 'Content-Type': 'application/json' },
    data: {"month":month}
}).then(function (data) {
    $scope.room_electricity = data.data.result;
    console.log(data.data.result)
});```
Thanks for your response.

Answer (score 0):

So log2 correctly prints undefined because the result from the post comes asynchronously, therefore the code goes beyond your $.post call and when the response comes, then it is filled with the data ( and log1 is printed).

Now for the html part, from the look of it, it is a typo since you in your controller the variable is named userdata and in the hmtl is called data. 
So simply change $scope.userdata to $scope.data and it will be fine.

Comment: That's a typo in the post, that's not the actual code. Posted a similar scenario. Corrected the typo. Any way to render Html page after the $.post block completes its execution?